# Parse Platform Kotlin relation many to many

Tags: kotlin, parse-platform, relation

Hi I'm learning Parse Database and I cannot make relation many to many. I have Users and Categories tables and I made Entity UserCategory table with userId and categoryId. Many users can have a lot of categories, and every category can have a lot of users. I tryed like this:

```
val category = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Category").whereMatches("name", "Employee")
   
    val entity = ParseObject("UserCategory")
    entity.put("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
    entity.put("categoryId", category) <- here is an error that invalid type for value: class com.parse.ParseQuery

    entity.save()
```

I want to make this that some user to match to some specific category. How I should do this? Maybe I have a wrong table design? But I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```kotlin
val category = await ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Category").whereMatches("name", "Employee").find()
   
    val entity = ParseObject("UserCategory")
    entity.put("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId())
    entity.put("categoryId", category.getObjectId()) <- here is an error that invalid type for value: class com.parse.ParseQuery

    entity.save()
```